# Opening a navigation controller from Tabbar with back button on first ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I know this question has been asked so many times on the SO, but I am asking this just because it is relevantly different and also some answers are out dated and some are in Objective-c which I can not understand properly.

**USE CASE:**

I have a UITabBar controller, and it is working fine. Let say I have 4 tabs in it and user click on the button given in the Tab 4. now on it I have to open some series of View Controllers. let say User has following patteren to follow.

4.A-->4.B--> 4.C  and can go back to first like so:  4.C-->4.B-->4.A

And finally User must also be allowed to go back to Tab4 after closing 4.A view controller

**WHAT I DID:**
I am able to open the View controller using this code.

```
let VC1 = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier :"myVcId") as! UIViewController
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: VC1) // Creating a navigation controller with VC1 at the root of the navigation stack.
    self.present(navController, animated:true, completion: nil)
```

This is opening a navigation controller and having me navigate the view controller as per my requirements but I want following thing too

**WHAT I WANT:** As I am presenting the Navigation Controller modally, I want to show the back button at very first view controller, and I want that if user select back button it kills all the Navigation controller and go the previous view controller where he came from

Comment: `it kills all the Navigation controller and go the previous view controller where he came from` impossible, there is no previous view controller so you want to kill the app or what? you would have to reload Tabbar and remove this tab

Comment: 4.A-->4.B--> 4.C and can go back to first like so: 4.C-->4.B-->4.A

 can give more description about this not getting anything

Comment: @Lu_ no, let suppose I am on any tab on the View Controller, and then I want to show the New NavigationController\

Comment: there is no such use case, but you can just add that button programmatically and keep In UserDefaults list of visited tabs if you really want that

Comment: @Lu_ check updated question

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the 4th tab and embed it inside a navigation then do

```
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier :"myVcId") as! UIViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

then you'll see a back on that first vc , to return to that tab do

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

Comment: I set Tab4 as example. There is some particular condition that can be fulfilled at any level from any view controller, so I need to go back from where this UINavigation controller is called

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, your structure looks like this:
A TabBarController, with ViewControllers as tabs, and from them you present a navigation controller with other ViewControllers, like this:

[image: image 1]

(TabBar) -vc-> (View) -present-> (NavController) -root-vc-> (View)

---

I have two suggestions for making it easier to handle.

**First option**

Use navigation controllers as tabs for your TabBarController, and make your ViewControllers that are tabs their root view controllers.

[image: image 2]

(TabBar) -vc-> (NavController) -root-vc-> (View) -push-> (View)

---

**Second option**

Another option is to use a navigation controller as your initial view controller, and make your tab bar this navigation controller's root view controller.

[image: image 3]

(NavController) -root-vc-> (TabBar) -view-> (View) -push-> (View)

---

Both options should work, and the first one should be a little easier to handle.

Comment: No , I have simple tabbar controller. Now I have some criteria if that does match in any of the tabbar view Controller let say Tab1, or Tab4 or any where , if criteria is matched then I want to take user to the new Modally presented UINavigationController. now from here he can go to like View1, to View 2 and View 3 and so on. And back to View 1 and there on View1, he may want to go back to from where he came, So I want to show the back button on the very first view controller

Comment: Instead of using Tab1 - Tab4 as the viewControllers of your TabBarController, create one NavigationController for each tab, and set them as your TabBarController's viewControllers. Then make Tab1 - Tab4 the rootViewControllers of your NavigationControllers. Instead of presenting a new navigation controller modally, then just push View1 - View 3 on the already existing NavigationController.

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate the navigationController with 4A as the rootViewController.

Then, in the `viewDidLoad` for 4A, you need to instantiate 4B, and push it to your navigationController.

Then, finally, in your 4B viewController's `viewDidLoad` you need to instantiate 4C and push it to your navigationController's stack.

*P.S.: Push all the viewControllers without animations.*

This should be achieving your strange scenario.

**EDITED:**

> You need your 4th tab from your tabBar to be a navigationController,
>   and its root view Controller to be the initial VC which will then push
>   your new navController, otherwise you won't have the `back` button.

So, your stack should be something like this:

```
                                     4CVC
                                       |-(push)
                                     4BVC
                                       |-(push)
                                     4AVC
                                       |-(push)
                                newNavController
                                       |-(push)
                                     someVC
                                       |
                                  navController
                                       |
tab1        tab2         tab3         tab4
                   |
                 tabBar
```

Comment: You did not get it completely.

Comment: What exactly am I missing?
You want to go back to where you initially instantiated the navigationController with all those 4A, 4B, 4C? Then you need to push your new navigationController onto the previous navController, otherwise, you won't have the `back` button.

Comment: I edited my answer. I hope this time I got it right.

Comment: actually navController can be open from any tab. i.e tab1, tab2, tab3, tab4 
not only always tab4. and I want to return data back to opening tab

Comment: @A.s.ALI apply the same logic that I described to any of your tabs.